# Evaluating the integral in polar

Tags: integration

I am trying to show that the double integral of $\sqrt{\rho^2-y^2}$ for $x$ between $0$ and $\rho$ while $y$ is between $0$ and $\sqrt{\rho^2-x^2}$ is $(2/3)(\rho)$.

In cartesian I have tried its proving but I have problems with transformation to polar

Comment: I don't think you can have both three variables $x,y,\rho$ (as independent) in the integral... polar coordinates are just $\rho$ and the angle, $x$ and $y$ shouldn't be there. I mean, isn't $\rho^2-y^2$ just $x^2$?

Comment: I suppose that rho is the radius of the disc as the relationship between the  variables x,y and rho seem to represent the disc of radius rho.

Comment: I want more of this and I am really thankful of stackexchange team for your help. I feel like I am learning now.

Answer (score 1):

let $\rho=a$. The integral is now
$$
\int_0^{a}\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\sqrt{a^2-y^2}dydx=I.
$$
Changing the order of integration we get
$$ 
I=\int_0^{a}\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dxdy=\int_0^{a}[(\sqrt{a^2-x^2})x]_{x=0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dy
    \int_0^{a}(a^2-y^2)dy=\frac23a^3.
$$

Comment: Could you please use Mathjax. This is not at all presentable and legible.

Answer (score 1):

The hard way: Region of integration is the part of the origin-centered disc of radius $\rho$ that is in the $1$st quadrant.
$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^\rho\int_0^\sqrt{\rho^2-x^2}\sqrt{\rho^2-y^2}\mathrm{dydx}\\
=&\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_0^\rho\sqrt{\rho^2-r^2\sin^2\theta }\,r\mathrm{\,dr\,d\theta}\tag{Cartesian to polar}\\
=&{1\over2}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_0^{\rho^2}\sqrt{\rho^2-r\sin^2\theta }\mathrm{\,dr\,d\theta}\tag{$r\mapsto r^2$}\\
=&{1\over2}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_0^{\rho^2}\sqrt{\rho^2\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta }\mathrm{\,dr\,d\theta}\tag{Uncouple $r,\theta$ to make...}\\
=&{1\over2}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_0^{\rho^2}\sin\theta\sqrt{\rho^2\cot^2\theta+r }\mathrm{\,dr\,d\theta}\tag{...integration easier}\\
=&{1\over2}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_{\rho^2\cot^2\theta}^{\rho^2\csc^2\theta}\sin\theta\sqrt{r}\mathrm{\,dr\,d\theta}\tag{$r\mapsto\rho^2\cot^2\theta+r$}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}(\csc^3\theta-\cot^3\theta)\sin\theta\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}{1-\cos^3\theta\over1-\cos^2\theta}\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}{\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta+1\over1+\cos\theta}\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\left(1+{\cos^2\theta\over1+\cos\theta}\right)\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\left(1+{\cos^2\theta-1\over1+\cos\theta}+{1\over1+\cos\theta}\right)\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\left(\cos\theta+{1\over1+\cos\theta}\right)\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\left(\cos\theta+{1\over2}\sec^2{\theta\over2}\right)\mathrm{\,d\theta}\\
=&{\rho^3\over3}\left[\sin\theta+\tan{\theta\over2}\right]\Big{|}_0^{\pi\over2}\\
=&{2\rho^3\over3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: how is (rho) changing to square of rho?

Comment: By the transformation $r\to r^2$

Comment: still not clear

Comment: Thanks man, I have noted it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25671/discussion-between-doctor-ngilazi-banda-joshua-and-jacks-wasted-life).